# Is there any way to create backup copy of a file, without type its name twice?

Tags: command-line, bash, cp

Often when I'm editing some system file first I create a backup copy. For example:

```
sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.bak
```

Is there any simple 'shortcut' such as:

```
sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config %s.bak
```

?

---

A workaround that I found is to use `sed` in this way:

```
sudo sed '' /etc/ssh/sshd_config -i.bak
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use brace expansion like this:

```
cp example_file{,.bak}
```

Comment: Oh, so nice! +1...

Comment: You beat me, very elegant :-)

Comment: to be safer `cp -n example_file{,.bak}`

Comment: let  (GNU) cp handle the backup: `cp -v -f -b -T file{,}` (also numbered backups are available)

Comment: to be even more safer `cp -nv example_file{,.bak};`

Answer (score 5):

### 1. What you asked for

You can create a small shellscript file `bupper`:

I have a directory `~/bin`, where I keep such help files.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
 cp -pvi "$1" "${1}.bak"
else
 echo "Info:  $0 copies to a backup file"
 echo "Usage: $0 <file to be backed up with .bak extension>"
fi
```

Make it executable,

```
chmod ugo+x bupper
```

When in `~/bin`, it will be in PATH and you can run it like any executable program anywhere (where you have write permissions).

Example:

```
$ bupper hello.txt 
'hello.txt' -> 'hello.txt.bak'
$ bupper hello.txt 
cp: overwrite 'hello.txt.bak'? n
$ bupper hello.txt 
cp: overwrite 'hello.txt.bak'? y
'hello.txt' -> 'hello.txt.bak'
```

### 2. Alternative - let the editor do the job automatically

Some editors have an option to create a backup copy of the file before you save a new version. This backup has often a tilde as the last character (tilde is the extension, but there is no dot before it).

**Gedit, the standard editor in Ubuntu is one of them.**

[image]

After setting `gedit` to save such a backup copy:

```
gedit hello.txt
```

And check afterwards

```
$ ls hello.txt*
hello.txt  hello.txt~  hello.txt.bak
```

Now **`hello.txt~`** has been added to `hello.txt` and the backup created by `bupper`.

**This works with `nano` too, with the option `-B`**

```
nano -B hello.txt
```

so you can do it with a command line editor for 'sudo' tasks :-)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This was my first idea, but I must have script as this on every machine which I'm using.

Comment: @pa4080, 75andyd's solution is elegant and portable (when you have learned it by heart). But I edited my answer to add a workaround - to let the editor do the job automatically. You can make Gedit create a backup file 'hello.txt' -> **'hello.txt~'** and there are other editors that have the same option. This alternative is *very convenient*.

Comment: nano -B only seems to have one backup version ie notes.txt~