# How do I change the ownership of certain sub-directories recursively?

Tags: command-line

I have a directory with about 100 sub directories. Some of these sub directories are "Wordpress folders" others are not. What I would like to do is change the ownership of the `themes` and `plugin` directories inside the "Wordpress folders". I'm using this command to get the list of these directories:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -type d | grep 'wp-content/themes\|wp-content/plugins'
```

How could I make change the ownership of all `plugins` and `themes` subdirectories?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question ([edit]). You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I used this command to get a list of the Wordpress folders: `find . -maxdepth 3 -type d  | grep 'wp-content/themes'`

Comment: You should rather use `find . -maxdepth 3 -type d -path "*wp-content/themes*"` and always add additional information directly to your question with [edit], but that still doesn't clarify much. What's the overall problem, what *exactly* do you want to achieve? Does the `find` command list all the directories you want to modify?

Comment: Add how to identify your folders. Is there any reason why you can't just do `chown -R user:group */wp-content/themes`?

Comment: You could modify your command in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5249797/6543935): `find . -maxdepth 3 -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*wp-content/(themes|plugins)' -exec echo chown -R User:Group {} \;`. Tweak the `User:Group` part. When the output looks sufficient remove `echo` to do the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your command in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5249797/6543935):

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*wp-content/(themes|plugins)' -exec echo chown -R user:group {} +
```

- Change the `user:group` pair with the actual user and group.
- Change the end of the `find` command from `{} +` to `{} \;` to output separate commands for each directory - it could be more easy to read ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085237/6543935)).
- Remove `echo` to do the changes.

---

I'm afraid that @muru's [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977328/how-do-i-change-the-ownership-of-certain-sub-directories-recursively#comment1571023_977328) is more elegant :) It could be modified in [this way](https://askubuntu.com/a/962511/566421):

```
echo chown -R user:group */wp-content/{themes,plugins}
```

- Change the `user:group` pair with the actual user and group.
- Remove `echo` to do the changes.

Comment: You could use the `{} +` form of `-exec` too.