# Copy group of files (Filename*) to backup (Filename*.bak)

Tags: command-line, cp, ms-dos

#### Background

In Linux you can:

- List a group of files with `ls Filename*`
- Remove a group of files with `rm Filename*`
- Move a group of files with `mv Filename* /New/Directory`
- But you **cannot** copy a group of files with: `cp Filename* *.bak`

#### Change Linux `cp` command to copy group of files

I have a group of files I'd like to copy without entering the names one by one and using the `cp` command:

```
$ ls gmail-meta3*
gmail-meta3                          gmail-meta3-REC-1558392194-26467821
gmail-meta3-LAB-1558392194-26467821  gmail-meta3-YAD-1558392194-26467821
```

How can I use something like the old DOS command `copy gmail-meta3* *.bak`?

I don't want to type similar command four times:

```
cp gmail-meta3-LAB-1558392194-26467821 gmail-meta3-LAB-1558392194-26467821.bak
```

I'm looking for a script/function/app that accepts parameters for old and new filename group and not something with hard-coded filenames. For example, a user can type:

```
copy gmail-meta3* *.bak
```

or they might type:

```
copy gmail-meta3* save-*
```

Comment: The issue looks to me using glob operator twice which none of your other commands use. bash isn't smart enough to handle it.

Comment: @qwr, the fact that bash expands metacharacters and tokenizes the input prior to handing it off to a command to be exec'ed is part of the design of the UNIX shells. To somehow try and program an exception for the cp command would break the entire consistency of bash, which would not be smart at all. As an exercise, try and figure out what is happening here, and why it is the shell's metacharacter expansion that makes it so: `touch aa ab ba; mkdir bb; cp a* b*; ls *`

Comment: @MikeS Thanks for the pointers. Yesterday someone else said you can use a wildcard `*` for the source filenames but not for the target filenames. As such as substitute wildcard (I think `##` was suggested but I'm leaning towards `%`) will have to be used for the target. I think this is what you are reinforcing? I didn't expect to change the `cp` command at all. Just create a wrapper script called `copy` that emulated (within reason) the DOS copy command.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix that person was correct. The shell metacharacters are independent of the commands. So all wildcards will try and match all files that match the pattern. If you're trying to make a general-purpose "match everything and copy them to whatever they were but add this suffix" program, then yes, putting an _unescaped_ metacharacter as the target will probably not do what you want. Because *all* metacharacters in the shell command line are expanded. If you KNOW for certain that the target metacharacter will never form a match, you could use it- because the shell can't expand it.

Comment: ...but that would be an ugly thing to do. Better to use a special character. % or underscore are good, they're generally not metacharacters (but be careful of using % in a crontab file; it's special there).

Comment: If you are interested, I have a script that does this with several config options, as well as one that does the inverse (remove the **.bak** from *.bak files).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote this one-liner into my `~/.bashrc`. Much better answers using `find` can be posted I suppose. Even better answers could be written in in C. Hopefully this Q&A gets the ball rolling for better answers:

```bash
cps () {
    # cps "Copy Splat", copy group of files to backup, ie "cps Filename .bak"
    # Copies Filename1 to Filename1.bak, Filename2 to Filename2.bak, etc.
    # If Filename1.bak exists, don't copy it to Filename1.bak.bak
    for f in "$1"*; do [[ ! "$f" == *"$2" ]] && cp -a "$f" "$f$2"; done

    # OLD version comments suggested to remove 
    # ls "$1"* | while read varname; do cp -a "$varname" "$varname$2"; done
}
```

- `for f in "$1"*; do` : `$1` is the `gmail-meta3` parameter and `f` is the list of files matching. Combined this means for gmail-meta3, gmail-meta3-LAB-9999, etc. do the following
- `[[ ! "$f" == *"$2" ]] &&` : `$f` is the same as `f` above. `$2` is the `.bak` parameter passed. Combined this means if the filename doesn't end in `.bak` (because we don't want to copy `.bak` and create `.bak.bak`) then do the following
- `cp -a "$f" "$f$2";` copy gmail-meta3 to gmail-meta3.bak, etc.
- `done` : loop back and grab next filename in `gmail-meta3`* list.

---

### `cps gmail-meta3 .bak` Sample Output

Using the question as an example here is how it looks in action:

```bash
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/gmail$ ll gmail-meta3*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 26467821 May 20 16:43 gmail-meta3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 26467821 May 20 16:43 gmail-meta3.bak
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick      643 May 20 16:43 gmail-meta3-LAB-1558392194-26467821
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick      643 May 20 16:43 gmail-meta3-LAB-1558392194-26467821.bak
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick    49607 May 20 16:44 gmail-meta3-REC-1558392194-26467821
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick    49607 May 20 16:44 gmail-meta3-REC-1558392194-26467821.bak
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick   728954 Jun 27 17:04 gmail-meta3-YAD-1558392194-26467821
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick   728954 Jun 27 05:46 gmail-meta3-YAD-1558392194-26467821.bak
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/gmail$ cps gmail-meta3 .bak
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/gmail$ ll gmail-meta3*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 26467821 May 20 16:43 gmail-meta3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 26467821 May 20 16:43 gmail-meta3.bak
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick      643 May 20 16:43 gmail-meta3-LAB-1558392194-26467821
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick      643 May 20 16:43 gmail-meta3-LAB-1558392194-26467821.bak
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick    49607 May 20 16:44 gmail-meta3-REC-1558392194-26467821
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick    49607 May 20 16:44 gmail-meta3-REC-1558392194-26467821.bak
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick   728954 Jun 27 17:04 gmail-meta3-YAD-1558392194-26467821
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick   728954 Jun 27 17:04 gmail-meta3-YAD-1558392194-26467821.bak
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/gmail$
```

**Note:** This uses the `-a` flag with the `cp` command to preserve timestamps and give you better grasp of your file backups.

Notice how the file copies have the exact same date and time as the originals. If the `-a` parameter was omitted they would be given the current date and time and wouldn't look like a true backup except that the file size would be the same.

Comment: don't people always recommend against parsing `ls`

Comment: Since you mention `find` I assume you’re aware of the dangers of parsing `ls`? But in your case neither is necessary: just do `for file in "$1"*; do copy -a "$file" "$file$2"; done` — this is completely safe and much simpler than any kind of indirection via `ls` or `find` and a `while` loop.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for your suggestion. I implemented and tested your suggestion with a couple minor changes.

Answer (score 20):

Here is an example of one atypical usage of `sed`, that is applicable in this case:

```
sed -i.bak '' file-prefix*
```

In this way, actually, `sed` will not change the files, because we do not provide any commands `''`, but due to the option `-i[suffix]` it will create a backup copy of each file. I found this approach when I was asking   [Is there any way to create backup copy of a file, without type its name twice?](https://askubuntu.com/q/962489/566421)

Comment: It probably doesn't matter what storage device you have for these tests, if this is happening on a Linux machine. The kernel is extremely good at buffering files in memory. That's what the "buff/cache" value is when using the `free` command. Actual writes to the device take place at a moment chosen by an algorithm that takes into account age of the cache and memory pressure on the machine. If you're trying multiple tests, then the first file reads will come off the disk but subsequent reads will most likely come straight out of memory (see `sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`).

Comment: Yesterday I made few tests with large files over 2GB and - yes, this approach is relatively slow than using of the `cp` command, but **I can't say there is any significant performance difference**.

Comment: Although I upvoted your answer and all the others in this thread I regret to say I've accepted my own answer tonight. I used `cps last .bak` in the command line and four files in my directory were copied. I didn't need to remember `sed` command syntax you posted here two years ago. It's rather brilliant though.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `find`:

```
find . -max-depth 1 -name 'gmail-meta3*' -exec cp "{}" "{}.bak" \;
```

That will find in the current directory `.` all files with a name matching the glob pattern (mind the single quotes around the pattern to prevent shell globbing). For each file found, it will exec `cp` from name to name.bak. The \; at the end ensures it will do each file individually instead of passing all of them at once. The max depth as 1 only searches the cuurent directory instead of recursing down.

Comment: Will it work with `find . -max-depth 1 -name '"$1"'' -exec cp "{}" "{}$2" \;` when $1 is source and $2 is extension?

Comment: $2 should be ok to substitute so long as it is reasonable. $1 could be trickier as we can't do variable substitution inside single quotes. I'm not sure offhand but it might be possible to use $1 in double quotes since the pattern is stored in a string.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a **`for` loop with `bash`**. Normally, I would just type it as a one-liner because this isn't a task I perform often:

```bsh
for f in test* ; do cp -a "$f" "prefix-${f}.ext" ; done
```

However, if you need it as a script:

```bsh
cps() {
   [ $# -lt 2 ] && echo "Usage: cps REGEXP FILES..." && return 1

   PATTERN="$1" ; shift

   for file in "$@" ; do
      file_dirname=`dirname "$file"`
      file_name=`basename "$file"`
      file_newname=`echo "$file_name" | sed "$PATTERN"`

      if [[ -f "$file" ]] && [[ ! -e "${file_dirname}/${file_newname}" ]] ; then
         cp -a "$file" "${file_dirname}/${file_newname}"
      else
         echo "Error: $file -> ${file_dirname}/${file_newname}"
      fi
   done
}
```

Usage is similar to  `rename`. To test:

```bsh
pushd /tmp
mkdir tmp2
touch tmp2/test{001..100}     # create test files
ls tmp2
cps 's@^@prefix-@ ; s@$@.bak@' tmp2/test*    # create backups
cps 's@$@.bak@' tmp2/test*    # more backups ... will display errors
ls tmp2
\rm -r tmp2                   # cleanup
popd
```

Comment: FYI: `$ time for f in gmail-meta3* ; do cp -a "$f" "${f}.bak" ; done` = `real 0m0.046s`

Comment: Um no I don't want to optimize for time. It is `0.046` seconds which means 0 seconds for human perception. I was just trying to show how I was testing posted answers and passing along interesting tidbits to viewers who looked at the `sed` command above. Or at least I was interested in comparing `sed` to `cp`....

Comment: Your solution with `cp` is faster than solution with `sed` though. So it's a cause for celebration :)

Comment: (1) `-a` is a non-standard test operator.  Why not use `-e`?  (2) “Unable to create temporary directory.” is a somewhat misleading error message.  (3) Why not just use `mktemp -d`?  (4) You should test exit statuses.  For example, you should say ``! mkdir "$FOLDER" && echo "Unable to create temporary directory." && return 1`` or ``mkdir "$FOLDER" || { echo "Unable to create temporary directory."; return 1;}``.  Likewise for `cp` and `rename` (and maybe even `pushd`, if you want to be careful).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) Arrggghhhh!  Don’t say `$@`; say `"$@"`. (5b) [There’s no need to use `{` and `}`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/80216#286525 "${variable_name} doesn’t mean what you think it does …") when you reference variables the way you are doing (`"${FOLDER}"`, `"${PATTERN}"` and `"${file}"`); just do `"$FOLDER"`, `"$PATTERN"` and `"$file"`. (6) This assumes that files are in the current directory.  `cps 's/$/.bak/' d/foo` will copy `d/foo` to `foo.bak` *in the current directory,* not `d/foo.bak`.

Comment: @G-Man 1. Done. 2. N/A b/c scrapped the `rename` script. 3. N/A. 4. Tried. Testing exit statuses doesn't work. Don't know why. 5. Done. 6. Rewrote to work with files that may not be contained in current directory.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Rewrote to work with files that aren't in the current directory and to use regular expressions via `sed`. May be slower than previous versions.

Comment: @xiota: Well, that’s a bit of a shame; I thought the idea of piggybacking on the existing ``rename`` program was brilliant, even if the implementation was flawed. But +1 for making the improvements.

Comment: @G-Man Couldn't figure out how to fix problems you pointed out while still using `rename`.

Answer (score 6):

The closest you will likely get to the DOS paradigm is `mcp` (from the `mmv` package):

```
mcp 'gmail-meta3*' 'gmail-meta3#1.bak'
```

If `zsh` is available, its contributed `zmv` module is perhaps a little closer:

```
autoload -U zmv

zmv -C '(gmail-meta3*)' '$1.bak'
```

---

I'd avoid `ls` regardless - a variant on [your own answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1153995/178692) that's safe for whitespace (including newlines) would be

```
printf '%s\0' gmail-meta3* | while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do cp -a -- "$f" "$f.bak"; done
```

or perhaps

```
printf '%s\0' gmail-meta3* | xargs -0 -I{} cp -a -- {} {}.bak
```

Comment: I understand `mmv` is the package but in comments you say the command is `mcp` but then in the command you use `mmv` which is also a command in `mmv` package. I like the direction of the `printf` examples and in a polished script I'd ensure $1 and $2 were passed. +1 for getting ball rolling :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix apologies - the mcp/mmv was a brainfart. Actually `mcp` is just a synonym for `mmv -c`

Comment: Pfft no worries. If I had a dollar for every typo I've made I'd be a millionaire :) I'd like clarification on `printf` command I've never used really. Are you saying `printf '%s\0' "$1"*` would work if `gmail-meta3` was passed as parameter 1?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'd probably let the calling context do the globbing i.e. `cps gmail-meta3*` and then write `printf '%s\0` "$@" | while ...` in the function. Or simply use `for f; do cp -- "$f" "$f.bak"; done` (like [xiota's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1154004/178692), but as a function)

Comment: Note that with `zmv` you can use "wildcard replacement" mode, which I find a bit easier to grok: `zmv -W -C 'gmail-meta3*' '*.bak'`

Comment: @0x5453 thanks - I wasn't aware of that option

Answer (score 5):

**rsync only solution**

If you just want to backup your files, you can copy them to a new directory

`rsync /path/to/dir/Filename* /path/to/backupdirectory`

This will copy the `Filename` files from `/path/to/dir/` to `/path/to/backupdirectory`.

---

**rsync + filerename**

If you want your backup files to have a suffix, things get hacky with `rsync`...

`rsync -Iu /path/to/dir/Filename* /path/to/dir/Filename* -b --backup-dir=/path/to/backupdirectory --suffix=.bak`

This would overwrite the existing files... with the existing files (`-I`) but only if they are (`-u`) newer (which they aren't) and creating a backup, with a suffix.

You can also do that in the same directory. But better exclude existing backups.

`rsync -Iu /path/to/dir/Filename* /path/to/dir/Filename* -b --backup-dir=/path/to/backupdirectory --suffix=.bak --exclude '*.bak'`

Comment: I love `rsycnc` so I upvoted but, a simpler method would be `cp Filename* /path/to/backup/dir` because files wouldn't need `*.bak` uniquifier if they were in a separate directory.

Answer (score 4):

This one should do as requested:

```bsh
cps(){ p="${@: -1}"; for f in "${@:1:$#-1}"; do cp -ai "$f" "${p//\?/$f}"; done  }
```

Usage:

```
cps FILES... pattern
Example 1: cps gmail-meta3* ?.bak
Example 2: cps * save-?
Example 3: cps * bla-?-blubb
```

I chose `?` because `#` must be quoted when it's the first character of pattern, otherwise it's recognized as the start of a comment.

Test:

```
$ touch 'test};{bla#?"blubb'
$ cps test* bla-?-blubb
$ ls
test};{bla#?"blubb  bla-test};{bla#?"blubb-blubb
```

---

---

Some earlier versions of the script for adding a suffix:

Similar to @WinEunuuchs2Unix answer, but I think more flexible and [not parsing `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead):

```bsh
cps(){ S="$1"; shift; printf '%s\0' "$@" | xargs -0 -I{} cp -abfS "$S" {} {}; }
```

Put this in your `.bashrc`.

Usage:

```
cps SUFFIX FILES...
Example: cps .bak gmail-meta3*
```

---

Alternative, with the suffix as last argument ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1854031/7365127) and [via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1215592/7365127)):

```bsh
cps(){ S="${@: -1}"; printf '%s\0' "${@:1:$#-1}" | xargs -0 -I{} cp -abfS "$S" {} {}; }
```

Usage:

```
cps FILES... SUFFIX
Example: cps gmail-meta3* .bak
```

---

Comment: Nice coding but it's kind of hard after decades of using *Source* then *Target* to switch copy command to *Target* then *Source*

Comment: Added the function with the suffix in the back.

Comment: Thanks that is more intuitive. Calling it a suffix is accurate the way my answer coded it but it's really a target or destination. Other users might want to use: `copy gmail-meta3* old-meta3*`. In my answer I couldn't figure out how to get `*` into the destination name like my question requested...

Comment: problem is that `*` is interpreted by the shell, so the function will not know about it. You would need some other character or quote it, then replace it with the original filename within the function.

Comment: I guess the `#` could be used as a replacement wildcard for `*`? So you could type `copy filenames# save-#`. I think you'd want the wildcard character to be the same for source and target.

Comment: I added one with pattern, that should be pretty much what you want, but I let the filenames be chosen from the shell outside the function, so I use * for the files and # for the pattern. I think it's better.

Answer (score 2):

Another method of achieving your requirement is to copy the files to a temporary directory and use the `rename` command to rename them.

```
$ mkdir backup
$ cp filename* /tmp/rename-backup/
$ rename 's/(filename.*)/$1.bak/' /tmp/rename-backup/*
$ mv /tmp/rename-backup/* ./
```

If you need it as a script, you can use it like so

```bsh
cps () {
    mkdir -p /tmp/rename-backup/
    cp "$1"* /tmp/rename-backup/
    rename "s/($1.*)/\$1.$2/" /tmp/rename-backup/*
    mv "/tmp/rename-backup/$1"*".$2" .
}
```

And you can use it like so:

```
cps file bak
```

This is an example

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:23 file a
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:23 file ab
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:23 file ac
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:05 filename1
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:05 filename2
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:05 filename3
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:05 filename4
$ cps file bak
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:23 file a
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:41 file a.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:23 file ab
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:41 file ab.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:23 file ac
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:41 file ac.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:05 filename1
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:41 filename1.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:05 filename2
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:41 filename2.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:05 filename3
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  wheel  0 Jun 26 16:41 filename3.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:05 filename4
-rw-r--r--  1 danny  danny  0 Jun 26 16:41 filename4.bak
```